# Splitting a list of dates at a specific value in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split a list of dates (in YYYY-MM-DD format) *at* a specific date and take all the entries including and after it.

```
desired_date = '2018-11-01'
my_list =  ['2018-10-29', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
```

What I'd like to do is split the list where `'2018-11-01'` appears, and obtain a shortened list like so:

```
shortened_list = ['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
```

Would appreciate any pointers! Thanks!

Comment: For a lazy approach, you can use `itertools.takewhile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `index()` to get the index of desired element and then just use *list slicing*:

```
desired_date = '2018-11-01'
my_list =  ['2018-10-29', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']

print(my_list[my_list.index(desired_date):])
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
```

Comment: That's it! I totally forgot about `.index()`. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome and do not forget to accept the answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: Yep! I'm just waiting for the time limit to be up so I can accept it.

Comment: Another improvement in case the `desired_date` is not in `my_list`:
```desired_date = '2018-11-01'```
`my_list =  ['2018-10-29', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']`
`shortened_list = [x for x in my_list if x >= desired_date]`
`print(shortened_list)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to parse elements in the array to date format first, and looping on the array to extract the needed date range.
Same as the previous answer

```
day_dt = '2018-11-01'
my_list =  ['2018-10-29', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
dt_list = [x for x in my_list if x >= day_dt]
print(dt_list)
```

In case you need filtering with Date

```
datetime.strptime(my_list[i], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Why? He is not trying to filter date objects.

Comment: I flagged not an answer for you answer. I suggest you to delete it or update it with the valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Another improvement in case the `desired_date` is not in `my_list`:

```
desired_date = '2018-11-01'
my_list =  ['2018-10-29', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
shortened_list = [x for x in my_list if x >= desired_date]
print(shortened_list)
```

Output

```
['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04']
```

I posted in answer because the comment field doesn't allow to write proper code